# Customization of UITableViewCell not doing anything

Tags: iphone, uitableview, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm having an issue I can't figure out.  I have a `UITableView` with a custom `UITableViewCell`.  I've set everything up as it should and that's fine.  Now I have a `UIImageView` in my `UITableViewCell`.  What I'm trying to do is customize the objects inside the UITableView like this `UIImageView` without using storyboard.  So I added the `UIImageView` using storyboard and then connected it as an IBOutlet to the custom `UITableViewCell` class file.

I'm starting of with a simple customization like:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    profilePictureImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 70, height: 70)

    println("Pic Dimensions: X:\(profilePictureImageView.frame.origin.x) Y:\(profilePictureImageView.frame.origin.y) W:\(profilePictureImageView.frame.size.width) H:\(profilePictureImageView.frame.size.height)")

}
```

The weird thing is the println statement is showing that I've changed the dimensions of the `UIImageView` as expected, the problem I am having is that this is not  being reflected in the UI.  The weird thing is that is I do some other sort of customization in the `awakeFromNib()` such as rounding the `UIImageView`, that works.  But repositioning it and changing dimensions doesn't seem to work, I don't get it.  By the way I am using XCode 6.1 + Swift

Comment: Autolayout is manipulating the view's dimensions. Either turn autolayout off or use constraints and manipulate them.

Comment: Wow, thank you, that did the trick!!  I was really trying to learn AutoLayout, but this thing is driving me nuts.  I'm now trying to do things in code to see how that works out.  I feel like AutoLayout causes more problems for me that needed.  I guess I'll see how this works out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the profilePictureImageView's frame in the layoutSubviews.